# How can I calculate this occurrence or association using (x+y)/x?

Tags: math, statistics, associations, recommendation-engine

What I'm trying to do here is calculate the percentage of IDS or "users" who rated Both M1 and M2. In Other words calculate the percentage of users who rated M1 but also M2... if a box is empty on either side it doesn't count...

For example on Row 2 is a user who rated both M's...

The formula or the method I'm supposed to use is X + Y / X ... and the result is supposed to be 46.7%... but I can't get that number. Please help and thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Nope, the X+Y/X in this context will not return anything <100% since X in this context is your number of records, so yes, you will not be able to get the number (In a percentage the divider is always the counter of the records). So something of the question you are posting here, is not 100% of your question involved. Also: SO is not a homework service.

Comment: Well, @NorbertvanNobelen I do appreciate your insightful comment but I have to comment that this is not for any sort of Homework, believe it or not, I'm just trying to solve this problem for the peace of mind of finding the solution as I have been trying for quite a while now.

Comment: Ok, no homework: Still the description is not sufficient. How do you define X and Y?

Answer (score 0):

Define a column "M1M2" that is the product of the values M1 and M2.

Then the non-zero elements in that column represent users that rated both.

The overall percentage is the number of non-zero elements in M1M2 divided by the overall number of Ids.